# create interactive marker on tilemill

Tags: interactive, marker, mapbox, tilemill

I am new to mapbox.js and tilemill, so please bear me.

I am trying to create an interactive map that when my mouse hover/click on the marker a customized tooltip/menu will show at the position where I want it to be, link in this example:
http://www.mapbox.com/map-sites/weekend-picks/

However when I use tilemill, I can only create tooltips that are at the upper-right corner of the map and there is very limited ways for me to customize the visual of the tooltip, I am hoping someone who has better experience with mapbox and tilemill can give me some advices,

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Weekend Picks example has markers from GeoJSON, brought in by MapBox.js - not rendered in TileMill. If you want that style of markers, you should likewise use GeoJSON and MapBox.js to put them on the map.

Comment: Thanks! I also discovered this from my side.